# TypeError: cannot read properties 'items' of undefined while making the custom selectbox/dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

I try to make the custom selectbox/dropdown list where I can click on 1 of the items inside of it and make it stay like that. When I have found probably the only one tutorial about it which kinda clearly shows how to do it I get TypeError even if I follow it 1:1. Whats going on?[image]

And the parent: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide items `prop` to `<Autocomplete />` which you are not doing.
So props is `undefined`

Try `<Autocomplete items = {[{id:1, value:"TEST"}, {id:2, value:"ASO"}]}>`

You missed out on passing super with `props`.

Your constructor should look like this.

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)
   this.state = {
      items : props.items || []
   }
}
```

Comment: But autocomplete is completely different component, it doesnt have any connections between eachother

Comment: In your autocomplete component you are trying to access this.props.items as per the image you have added.

Comment: Ohh yeah you pointed out my mistake, this class component had a wrong name. I changed it to 'Aso' but the problem is the same instead of 'new Autocomplete' says ' new Aso ' under TypeError

Comment: Check the updated answer and accept it, if it resolves your issue:)

Comment: The Hero I needed but didnt deserve for.. Thank you a lot man! :)

Comment: Glad, I was able to help:)